# I want to chnage the color of text inputted in my field

Tags: html, css, forms

the css code here is isn't changing the color of text inputted,,,please help

```
               ::placeholder
               {
                 color:white;
               }
            

                <input type="text"  placeholder="  Other Names">
```

Comment: Works fine, might be a CSS order issue.

Comment: `input[type="text"]::placeholder {   color:white; }`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work..I want to change the color of the text the user puts in

Comment: @DemiladeSamuel added a answer below

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple way to change inputed text color.

```css
input {
  color: red;
}

input.second {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to change the color of user input, not the placeholder. Here, the color of the default placeholder text (`Other Names` in this case) will be red, whereas the color of the text typed by the user will be green. Use whichever is applicable in your case.

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
input {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: okat..Thanks ,this works but affects my border color too which I don't want